# Stretch a page to fill a full half of a page when printing two pages on one

Tags: pdf, printing, printer

I am trying to print the [Swordfish Islands Worldbuilder's Print-It-Yourself Zine](https://shop.swordfishislands.com/worldbuilders-notebook-digital/) using a Canon MFW232W LaserJet Printer from Pop!_OS 21.08 from either Evince or Okular PDF viewers. I can get the pages to print 2 per page horizontally, but the pages do not seem to fill the whole half of a page. I don't think I did the correct sequence of configurations or buttons to get it to work. Would anyone have any advice on how to achieve this?

[image: Image. A photo showing two pages of the printed zine. The hexagonal grid printed in the middle of these two pages is reduced, resulting in large, blank margins on the top, bottom and outer edges of each page.]

The edges show where I am trying to make the pages expand. If this is the wrong StackExchange group, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the document contains page margins.

If yes:
Simplest solution; minimize / remove all margins in your printing.